# Как верно рассчитать количество символов для обрезки?

Tags: php, gd

Отрисовываю текст на изображении через GD. Мне надо сделать верные переносы слов. Т.е. слова не должны разрываться, но и не должно оставаться много пустого места. Использую `wordwrap`, но ему надо скормить верный второй параметр: количество символов. Т.е. мне надо посчитать сколько символов с заданным шрифтом поместится в указанную длину в пикселях. Также использую `imagettfbbox`, но в данном случае не знаю как ее можно применить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Могу посоветовать хорошую библиотеку [`PHPImage`](https://github.com/kus/php-image). Пример использования:

```
$image = new PHPImage(600, 400);

$image->rectangle(0, 0, 600, 400, [13, 33, 37], 1);
$image->setFont('font.ttf');
$image->setTextColor([255, 255, 255]);

$image->setStrokeWidth(1);
$image->setStrokeColor([13, 13, 55]);

$image->text('Верный рассчет количества символов для обрезки', [
    'fontSize' => 60,
    'width' => 600,
    'height' => 400,
    'alignHorizontal' => 'center',
    'y' => 50
]);

$image->setStrokeWidth(1);
$image->setStrokeColor([55, 7, 55]);

$image->textBox('Отрисовываю текст на изображении через библиотеку GD. Мне нужно сделать верные переносы слов, слова не должны разрываться, но и также не должно оставаться много пустого места. Также использую imagettfbbox.', [
    'width' => 500,
    'fontSize' => 20,
    'y' => 150,
    'x' => 60,
]);

$image->show();
```

Библиотека имеет много параметров, вот результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да неплохо. Эх, а я уже почти написал свою библиотеку. :D

Comment: @DarkByte, хд, тогда вам нужно только сама функция для правильного расчета и переноса текста?

Comment: Ну да, типа того. Попробую поковырять исходники этой либы, а может не буду заморачиваться и заюзаю ее уж тогда...

Comment: @DarkByte, советую исходник глянуть, думаю там не очень сложно :)

Answer (score -1):

```
$text = 'Привет';
$fontsize = 11;
echo mb_strlen($text, 'UTF-8') * imagefontwidth($fontsize);
```

Comment: `imagefontwidth` принимает дескриптор шрифта, а не его размер

Comment: @DarkByte я в курсе

Comment: Тогда зачем этот заведомо неверный пример?